# Upgraded to React 16, react-router-redux does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I recently upgraded the React version to 16, and since then, react-router-redux (I am using Redux) does not seem to work.  My code is too big to paste here. However, it looks very similar to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux.

This is what my code looks like:

```
//Combine the Epics
const rootEpic = combineEpics(
    storeEpic,
    shoppingListEpic,
    landingEpic,
    incrementalSearchEpic,
    completedSavedShoppingEpic
);

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic, {
    dependencies: {
        incrementalSearchService: IncrementalSearchServiceMock
    }
});

//Combine the reducers
const reducer = combineReducers({
    syncSpaceReducer,
    routing: routerReducer
});

const transitionHistory = createHistory();

const enhancer = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, epicMiddleware),
    handleTransitions(transitionHistory),
    DevTools.instrument()
);

const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
            <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
            <DevTools />
        </div>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('syncspace')
);
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the error that you are getting???

Comment: This is the error
warning.js?1792:33Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Answer (score 0):

try uninstalling und installing again this packages, they together are working for me:

```
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
```

Comment: I noticed that you are using react-router-dom, whereas I'm using react-router-redux

Comment: problems with tutorials are outdated, you don't need  react-router-redux; try a updated tutorial with react-router-dom only first. react-router-redux is beta

Comment: Yup, this actually fixed the problem for me as well.

Comment: you problem is solved? you can mark the answer like valid

Answer (score 0):

The version of react-router-redux that is compatible with React 16 is not in production yet. You can use their alpha version. They moved the repo within [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux).

As explained in their page, running `npm install --save react-router-redux@next` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-redux`is deprecated now. Instead, use `connected-react-router`.[image]